# Dell Venue Pro 8 - Wifi not on after reboot

Tags: dell-venue

After a reboot of fully updated Windows 8.1, the wifi adaptor is enabled but finds no networks.

Clicking disable and then enable kicks it into gear.

Tried older version of driver, disabling bluetooth and WWAN, no joy.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any bios updates available?

Comment: this is already up to date, also, sadly.